# Gsm network info in android

Tags: android, gsm

Does someone know how to get gsm information in android? Information like BCCH (Broadcast Control Channel) and BCIS (Base Station Identity Code). I already got the LAC (Location Area Code) and CID (Cell ID). I know that is a low level information but does someone know to get those information? I am having a hard time researching and i don't have an idea about cellular network. Please Help thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is function which gives you complete information of gsm network.
just Call with context from your activity

```
 private void getNWInfo(Context context) {
          /**
           * <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
           * /> <uses-permission
           * android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
           */

          TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                       .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
          String networkOperator = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
          int mcc = 0, mnc = 0;
          if (networkOperator != null) {
                 mcc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(0, 3));
                 mnc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(3));
          }

          String SimNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();

          String SimSerialNumber = telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
          String countryISO = telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso();
          String operatorName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
          String operator = telephonyManager.getSimOperator();
          int simState = telephonyManager.getSimState();

          String voicemailNumer = telephonyManager.getVoiceMailNumber();
          String voicemailAlphaTag = telephonyManager.getVoiceMailAlphaTag();

          // Getting connected network iso country code
          String networkCountry = telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso();
          // Getting the connected network operator ID
          String networkOperatorId = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
          // Getting the connected network operator name
          String networkName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();

          int networkType = telephonyManager.getNetworkType();

          String network = "";
          ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                       .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          try {
                 if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getTypeName().equals("MOBILE"))
                       network = "Cell Network/3G";
                 else if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getTypeName().equals("WIFI"))
                       network = "WiFi";
                 else
                       network = "N/A";
          } catch (Exception e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
          }

          TextView  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
          textView.setText("network :" + network +

          "\n" + "countryISO : " + countryISO + "\n" + "operatorName : "
                       + operatorName + "\n" + "operator :      " + operator + "\n"
                       + "simState :" + simState + "\n" + "Sim Serial Number : "
                       + SimSerialNumber + "\n" + "Sim Number : " + SimNumber + "\n"
                       + "Voice Mail Numer" + voicemailNumer + "\n"
                       + "Voice Mail Alpha Tag" + voicemailAlphaTag + "\n"
                       + "Sim State" + simState + "\n" + "Mobile Country Code MCC : "
                       + mcc + "\n" + "Mobile Network Code MNC : " + mnc + "\n"
                       + "Network Country : " + networkCountry + "\n"
                       + "Network OperatorId : " + networkOperatorId + "\n"
                       + "Network Name : " + networkName + "\n" + "Network Type : "
                       + networkType);


   }
```

you can find more details on this blog

http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/search?updated-max=2013-11-07T03:23:00-08:00&max-results=7

hope it will help you :)

Comment: how about bcch and bsic? Do you have an idea to retrieve those info?

Comment: please go through this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/tVyNMnXtcEI

Comment: You and anchit has the same answer. :( does low level info of network is not really possible to retrieve??

Comment: how about two sims ??

Comment: any way to get BTS ID?

Answer (score 2):

Please visit [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/tVyNMnXtcEI). It explains that no APIs are available to get the Radio Information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static JSONArray getCellInfo(Context ctx){
    TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    JSONArray cellList = new JSONArray();

    int phoneTypeInt = tel.getPhoneType();
    String phoneType = "unknown";
    if (phoneTypeInt == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM)
        phoneType = "gsm";
    else if (phoneTypeInt == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA)
        phoneType = "cdma";

    //from Android M up must use getAllCellInfo
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {

        List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighCells = tel.getNeighboringCellInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < neighCells.size(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject cellObj = new JSONObject();
                NeighboringCellInfo thisCell = neighCells.get(i);
                cellObj.put("cellId", thisCell.getCid());
                cellObj.put("lac", thisCell.getLac());
                cellObj.put("rssi", thisCell.getRssi());
                cellList.put(cellObj);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

    } else {
        List<CellInfo> infos = tel.getAllCellInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < infos.size(); ++i) {
            try {
                JSONObject cellObj = new JSONObject();
                CellInfo info = infos.get(i);
                if (info instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
                    CellSignalStrengthGsm gsm = ((CellInfoGsm) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                    CellIdentityGsm identityGsm = ((CellInfoGsm) info).getCellIdentity();
                    cellObj.put("cellId", identityGsm.getCid());
                    cellObj.put("lac", identityGsm.getLac());
                    cellObj.put("dbm", gsm.getDbm());
                    cellList.put(cellObj);
                } else if (info instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                    CellSignalStrengthLte lte = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                    CellIdentityLte identityLte = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellIdentity();
                    cellObj.put("cellId", identityLte.getCi());
                    cellObj.put("tac", identityLte.getTac());
                    cellObj.put("dbm", lte.getDbm());
                    cellList.put(cellObj);
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }

    return cellList;
}
```